# Vulkan Device - Host - Device synchronization with VkEvent

Tags: vulkan

I'm trying to synchronize a host stage into my pipeline, where I basically edit some data on the host during the execution of a command buffer on the device. From reading the specification I think I'm doing the correct synchronization, execution/memory dependencies and availability/visibility operations, but it neither works on NV nor AMD hardware. Is this even possible? If so, what am I doing wrong in terms of synchronization?

In summary I'm doing the following:

- [D] A device buffer (`VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT`) is copied to a host visible and coherent one (`VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT`).
- [D] The first event is set.
- [D] The second event is waited for.
- [H] Meanwhile the host waits for the first event.
- [H] After it has been set, it increments the numbers in the host visible buffer.
- [H] Then it sets the second event.
- [D] The device then continues to copy the host visible buffer back to the device local buffer.

#### What happens?

On NV the first part works, the correct data arrives at the host side, but the altered data never arrives at the device side. On AMD not even the first part works and I already don't get the data on the host.

#### Command buffer recording:

```
// ...
VkMemoryBarrier barrier = {};
barrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
barrier.srcAccessMask = ...;
barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT;
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(command_buffer, ..., VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, 0, 1, &barrier, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr);

copyWholeBuffer(command_buffer, host_buffer, device_buffer);

barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_HOST_READ_BIT;
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(command_buffer, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT, 0, 1, &barrier, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr);

vkCmdSetEvent(command_buffer, device_to_host_sync_event, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT);

barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT;
barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT;
vkCmdWaitEvents(command_buffer, 1, &host_to_device_sync_event, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, 1, &barrier, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr);

copyWholeBuffer(command_buffer, device_buffer, host_buffer);

barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
barrier.dstAccessMask = ...;
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(command_buffer, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, ..., 0, 1, &barrier, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr);
// ...
```

#### Execution

```
vkQueueSubmit(queue, 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE);

while(vkGetEventStatus(device, device_to_host_sync_event) != VK_EVENT_SET)
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(10));

void* data;

vkMapMemory(device, host_buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, &data);

// read and write parts of the memory

vkUnmapMemory(device, host_buffer);

vkSetEvent(device, host_to_device_sync_event);

vkDeviceWaitIdle(device);
```

I've uploaded a working example: https://gist.github.com/neXyon/859b2e52bac9a5a56b804d8a9d5fa4a5

The interesting bits start at line 292! Please have a look if it works for you?

Comment: why not split it into 2 cmd buffers and use a fence for sync?

Comment: That's the alternative in case this doesn't work at all. This should be the more optimized version: Only one queue submission and other commands in the command buffer can keep running in parallel, with two command buffers you certainly have to separate the commands temporally. You can run the host code in another thread than where the submission is done. Also this version would allow for nicer software design of my pipeline.

Comment: Do you actually reset your events somewhere?

Comment: In this example, the whole code just runs once and as the standard says "When created, the event object is in the unsignaled state." In my application where I'm trying to use it, I reset them before every command buffer submission as well.

Comment: I've uploaded a working example: https://gist.github.com/neXyon/859b2e52bac9a5a56b804d8a9d5fa4a5

The interesting bits start at line 292! Please have a look if it works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened an issue on github: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/755

After a bit of discussion there, the conclusion is that Device to Host synchronization is not possible with an event and a fence has to be used.